# Why does git only allow fast-forward merges when pushing?

Tags: git, github, system, conceptual

So I know that when you do a `git push`, git tries to integrate changes from your local branch to the corresponding remote branch. However, if the branches have diverged, git won't allow you to push, saying

> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally.

When a user pushes successfully, he expects that the remote branch he just pushed mirrors his own. If we allowed 3 way merges when pushing (only if there are NO conflicts), then the remote branch obviously wouldn't match his own because it has commits our local copy doesn't know about, as well as a merge commit. However, couldn't git just do a pull after a push if it required a 3 way merge? What are the downsides to allowing a 3 way merge when pushing in this fashion, and why did the creators of Git decide to only allow fast forward commits?

Here's a diagram to illustrate the situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDqWu.jpg

Comment: Because there's absolutely no guarantee that can be resolved in a safe and sensible way, and there are probably other people tracking that same remote. It's up to *you* to the the local copy into a compatible state, because you have *context*.

Comment: You are just trying to break the distributed nature of git. Stuff happens on a repo.... your repo. You are talking of doing operations on a different repo.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What if we limited the 3 way merge for pushes that have NO conflicts? In that case a merge should be a safe operation with no history rewritten, and even if others are tracking that remote branch, they can just `git pull` to get the latest updates.

Comment: @eftshift0 Can you please provide a more specific example of "breaking the distributed nature of git"? In what situations can this approach go bad?

Comment: Well what's the point of that? If it can be resolved so trivially, why haven't you done so? FWIW we rarely merge, mostly `pull -r` to keep a linear history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, the fact is that `git push` *never* does a merge.  (Another way to put this—I think perhaps a better one—is that Git's "fast-forward merge" is not a merge at all.)

As [matt noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446339/1256452), when you use GitHub's Pull Request feature,<sup>1</sup> GitHub makes available, to the person operating the target repository, a one-button-click method to really, actually do a merge using the commits you `git push`-ed, provided this merge can be done automatically.  But `git push` never even checks to see if a merge is possible: it just says that a merge, or some other action, *would be* required, to add your new commits to the target repository without dropping some commit(s) from the target branch.

The definition of *fast-forward* is:<sup>2</sup>

- Let *C<sub>old</sub>* be the commit hash ID currently identified by name *N*.
- Let *C<sub>new</sub>* be the commit hash ID you propose *N* should identify.
- The operation is a fast forward if and only if *C<sub>old</sub>* ≼ *C<sub>new</sub>*.

That funny symbol ≼ (Unicode PRECEDES OR EQUAL TO, U+227c) that looks like a curvy less-than-or-equal-to is what the Git command `git merge-base --is-ancestor` tests, i.e., that the old commit's hash ID is a predecessor of, or is the same commit as, the new commit's.  To put it yet another way, the old commit will still be *reachable* from the new commit: see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Merge commits have the peculiar property of having more than one parent commit hash ID, making more than one sub-graph of the overall commit DAG *reachable*.  Hence a simple way to keep some old sub-graph reachable while adding a new graph fragment is to add a merge commit.  The `git merge` command can add such a commit, but in the process, it does something arguably useful with the three commit *snapshots* that are inputs to the merge.

As [bk2204 noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446777/1256452), `git push` *could* detect the push failure and automatically invoke `git fetch` and `git merge` on your end.  You could write a script yourself to do the same thing.  But this isn't always the right thing to do, so it would need yet more configuration knobs.  I myself hold the opinion that `git pull`, which runs fetch and then merge for you, already does too much, and that such a control knob for `git push` would be *far* too much.

Anyway, you *could* write this yourself.  (It would perhaps help if `git push` reserved a particular exit status for "rejected due to non-fast-forward", perhaps, but there's yet another problem here: you can `git push` multiple *names* in one go, and can have some succeed and others fail, each for different reasons.)  Feel free to write it yourself—Git is, after all, a big box of tools, rather than one specific solution—but remember that some merges fail with merge conflicts.  Your command would need to limit the internal push step to push only the *current* branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>This really is a *GitHub* feature, not part of base Git.  Other web-hosting sites do provide a feature with the same *name* and very similar operation.  Obviously there's a strong desire for it.  But Git itself still does not have it, for at least technical reasons.  In particular, who should be the author and committer of a merge commit?  GitHub's answer is: wait until someone clicks the button, then use *that person's* information.  That person is usually *not* the person who made the pull request in the first place, but often not one particular person either: there may be a whole group of people allowed to approve PRs.  In any case, there is always a human in the loop.

<sup>2</sup>Well, this is *a* definition.  There are other equivalent ones you could formulate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I think the decision to only allow fast forward merges make sense now, because I realized that even if git allowed non-conflicting 3 way merges when pushing, this would require a `git pull` afterwards to get the new state of the remote. So there wouldn't be a benefit to doing this because instead of pulling before pushing, you're just puling after pushing + git would have to be doing a lot of stuff behind the scenes which isn't always the best idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Because by definition there is "nobody home" on the remote (online) copy of git that you are pushing to. So if there is a problem (conflict) who will resolve it and how?

If you use GitHub or similar, however, there is a way around this: make a Pull Request. That way, there is an interface for resolving issues *on the server*, and so the Pull Request can perform any kind of merge.

Comment: thanks for the response! If we only allowed conflict-less merges, there wouldn't be a need for "someone to be home", so would it still be a problem?

Comment: @rahultimate Yes, it would still be a problem, because the absence of conflict is only one test that confirms a merge is successful. A "good" merge should also pass all the test suites, and merge-on-push does not have a space to run the tests before merging. GitHub's PRs can trigger running the tests via GitHub Actions, and you can run the tests on your local machine after pulling and merging, so those approaches work, but a merge-on-push strategy would add that merge to the history untested, and that can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because overwriting the remote without a force push would lose data and other behaviors, such as automatically performing a merge, would be surprising and hard to reason about.

In many cases when performing a merge, the result is very logical and straightforward because one branch has relatively few changes.  However, there are times that merges produce behavior that's surprising or unexpected, such as producing a clean merge that doesn't compile.  As a result, it's much better to simply give up quickly if your changes aren't a superset of what's on the branch and let the user decide how to deal with it.

In addition, for the case that a user *did* want the current behavior, then there would still have to be an option for that, as well as an option to overwrite the current branch, since the latter is useful when rebasing.  So instead of having two options (regular and force pushes), there'd need to be three.

Finally, in some workflows, one doesn't wish to have merge commits, and so performing a merge would create an undesired nonlinear history.  Similarly, even if one does use a merge-based workflow, extra merge commits (e.g., merges from `master`) are often wanted, and users would be unhappy to find that they'd unexpectedly messed up their history.